# How to exclude referenced content folder from nuget package

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-spec

I have three referenced content folders from another project in my `.csproj` file:

```
 <Content Include="..\infrastructure\Content\**\*.*">
      <Link>Infrastructure\Content\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="..\infrastructure\fonts\**\*.*">
      <Link>Infrastructure\fonts\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="..\infrastructure\Scripts\**\*.*">
      <Link>Infrastructure\Scripts\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
```

I want to create a `nuget` package from my project without the included content files. I have tried this command:

```
nuget pack sampleproj.csproj -Exclude ../infrastructure/** -NoDefaultExcludes -IncludeReferencedProjects -Verbosity detailed
```

But it includes the above files. I have also tried these arguments for `-Exclude` with no success:

```
infrastructure/**
../../infrastructure/**
bin/infrastructure/**
```

When I use `**/infrastructure/**` it works, but also excludes some files that I need them to be packaged.

How can I exclude referenced content files?

**P.S**: in my `.nuspc` file I have only one `file` element: `<file src="cassette-cache\**" target="Content" />` .